# Converting Numpy Structured Array to Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I obtain a structured numpy array from the following code:

```
data = np.genfromtxt(fname, dtype = None, comments = '#', skip_header=1, usecols=(ucols))
```

where the first column is the indices of the rest of the data set in a scrambled order (which I wish to preserve).
I would like to convert the structured array into a Pandas dataframe with the scrambled indices as the callable indices of the dataframe.

EDIT:

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([(45,1,'mars',1,1),(67,1,'pluto',1,1),(12,1,'saturn',1,1)],dtype='i,f,U10,i,f')
```

creates a numpy structured array, calling the first entry gives:

```
In [5]: test[0]
Out[5]: (45, 1., 'mars', 1, 1.)
```

calling the entire array:

```
In [6]: test
Out[6]: 
array([(45, 1., 'mars', 1, 1.), (67, 1., 'pluto', 1, 1.),
       (12, 1., 'saturn', 1, 1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<U10'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<f4')])
```

I want to turn this structured array into a pandas dataframe, and then in this example let 45,67,12 be the callable indices to access the data in the 'rows' of the array.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) together with the expected output?

Comment: Sure, I will make an edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the given example, you could let

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test).set_index('f0')
```

With that, you can access, say, the row whose index is 45 through `df.loc[45]`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've done `import pandas as pd` already:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(test) # converts your array to a DataFrame.
df = df.set_index('f0') # changes the index to be the first column.
```

Comment: The code I posted creates a numpy structured array, I want to convert this structured array into a pandas dataframe with the first column as the callable indices of the dataframe